# How to download the SSL certificate (and the whole chain until the root) of a web site

Tags: ssl-certificate

Back in the day when chrome browser allowed to view the site certificate from the address bar padlock, I was able to view the certificates and it's roots (at least on the Windows OS) and able to download them. Now that with the recent chrome versions (2023 Sept onwards) things got changed a bit (Chrome now ships with it's own [Chrome Root store](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/net/data/ssl/chrome_root_store/faq.md#What-is-the-Chrome-Root-Store) instead of relying on OS) and I no longer can download the certificates.!

Is there a known software or cli that given a URL can download the website's ssl, intermediate certs and the root ?

Comment: Why were you downloading them though?  I can't think of a legit reason someone needs to do this?

Comment: I'm behind Zescalar (Zero Trust security) which intercepts the certificates and changes the trust chain. I'm not sure how it does that. So, I use is to download the certificate and the one in trust chain and put them in java keystore.

Comment: Ahh I see, creepy but interesting.